# Phusion Passenger Standalone: Listen on two ports?

Tags: passenger, phusion

Is there a way to configure phusion passenger to listen on two ports, directing all traffic to a single application (multiple node.js processes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit Passenger Standalone's Nginx template to accomplish that. But in general, Passenger for Nginx is more suitable for such a use case.

If I'm not mistaken you're an enterprise customer. Why not contact the enterprise support channel directly? :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [--nginx-config-template](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/reference/#--nginx-config-template-nginx_config_template) option and insert the following:

```
server {
    listen 23403;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:12300;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```